# about Quick Sort

Tags: java, data-structures, sorting, quicksort

I have written this code but it will print these stack traces in the console please help me thanks! (Aslo "p" and "q" are the first and last index of our array ,respectively)

```
public class JavaQuickSort {

public static void QuickSort(int A[], int p, int q) {
    int i, last = 0;

    Random rand = new Random();
    if (q < 1) {
        return;
    }
    **swap(A, p, rand.nextInt() % (q+1));**

    for (i = p + 1; i <= q; i++) {
        if (A[i] < A[p]) {
            swap(A, ++last, i);
        }

    }
    swap(A, p, last);
    QuickSort(A, p, last - 1);
    QuickSort(A, last + 1, q);
}

private static void swap(int[] A, int i, int j) {
    int temp;
    temp = A[i];
    **A[i] = A[j];**
    A[j] = temp;


}
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] A = {2,5,7,3,9,0,1,6,8};
    **QuickSort(A, 0,8 );**
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
}
}
```

the Stack traces :

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -3
        at JavaQuickSort.swap(JavaQuickSort.java:38)
        at JavaQuickSort.QuickSort(JavaQuickSort.java:22)
        at JavaQuickSort.main(JavaQuickSort.java:45)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I also bold those statements that cause these stack traces. like ==> ** ...**

EDITED:

```
public class JavaQuickSort {

public static void QuickSort(int arr[],int lo,int hi) {
    int n = arr.length;
    if(n<=1)
        return;
    **int r = partition(arr);**
    **QuickSort(arr,lo , r-1);**
    QuickSort(arr, r+1, hi);
}

private static void swap(int[] A, int i, int j) {
    int temp;
    temp = A[i];
    **A[i] = A[j];**
    A[j] = temp;


}
public static int partition(int arr[]){
      int i, last = 0;
 Random rand = new Random();
    int n = arr.length;
    if (n <= 1)
        return arr[0];

    **swap(arr, 0, rand.nextInt(n));**

    for (i =1; i <n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[0]) {
            swap(arr, ++last, i);
        }

    }
    swap(arr, 0, last);
    return last;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] A = {2,5,7,3,9,0,1,6,8};
    **QuickSort(A, 0,8 );**
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
}
}
```

I have edited my post for being more understandable also it will print these stack traces and I bold the lines that cause these stack traces!!!

the stack traces :

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at JavaQuickSort.swap(JavaQuickSort.java:27)
        at JavaQuickSort.partition(JavaQuickSort.java:39)
        at JavaQuickSort.QuickSort(JavaQuickSort.java:19)
        at JavaQuickSort.QuickSort(JavaQuickSort.java:20)
        at JavaQuickSort.QuickSort(JavaQuickSort.java:20)
        at JavaQuickSort.QuickSort(JavaQuickSort.java:20)
        at JavaQuickSort.QuickSort(JavaQuickSort.java:20)
        at JavaQuickSort.main(JavaQuickSort.java:52)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

please help me thanks

EDITED :

I have written this code with paying attention to the forst answer of this post but it wont sort my array!!!

```
public class JavaQuickSort {

public static void QuickSort(int arr[], int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi > lo) {
         Random rand = new Random();
        int pivotIndex = lo + rand.nextInt(hi-lo+1);
        int pivotnewIndex = partition(arr, lo, hi,pivotIndex);
        QuickSort(arr, lo, pivotnewIndex - 1);
        QuickSort(arr, pivotnewIndex + 1, hi);
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] A, int i, int j) {
    int temp;
    temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;


}

public static int partition(int arr[],int lo,int hi,int pivotIndex)
{
    int pivotValue = arr[pivotIndex];
    swap(arr, hi, pivotIndex);
    int storeIndex = lo;
    for(int i = lo;i<hi;i++){
        if (arr[i]<=pivotValue)
        swap(arr, storeIndex, i);
        storeIndex = storeIndex ++;
    }
    swap(arr, storeIndex, hi);
    return storeIndex;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = {2, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1, 6, 8};
    QuickSort(A, 0, 8);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
}
}
```

the output:

```
run:
[2, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 7, 1, 5]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I need your help really I confused !!!

Comment: Please post the Stack Trace also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some problems with your code are:

- Don't create a new [`Random`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) instance for one time uses. Just create it once, store it in say a `static` field, and then use it to generate many random numbers for your application.
- When creating a random index for the pivot, it must lie between `p` and `q` inclusive.
- Use `Random.nextInt(int n)` overload to generate a random number in a given range
- Perhaps use `lo` and `hi` instead of `p` and `q`, and `int[] arr` instead of `int A[]`
- You can get the length of an array with its `.length` member

As for the quicksort algoritm itself, it doesn't look like anything I've seen before. I recommend studying the standard imperative implementation and adapting that.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

---

#### Update

Unfortunately you have mixed up the pseudocodes from Wikipedia somewhat. You want to adapt this algorithm:

```
  function partition(array, left, right, pivotIndex)
     pivotValue := array[pivotIndex]
     swap array[pivotIndex] and array[right] // Move pivot to end
     storeIndex := left
     for i  from  left to right - 1 // left ≤ i < right  
         if array[i] ≤ pivotValue 
             swap array[i] and array[storeIndex]
             storeIndex := storeIndex + 1
     swap array[storeIndex] and array[right] // Move pivot to its final place
     return storeIndex

  procedure quicksort(array, left, right)
     if right > left
         select a pivot index //(e.g. pivotIndex := left+(right-left)/2)
         pivotNewIndex := partition(array, left, right, pivotIndex)
         quicksort(array, left, pivotNewIndex - 1)
         quicksort(array, pivotNewIndex + 1, right)
```

Note that the above algorithm selects the middle element of the subarray between `left` and `right` for the pivot index. Since you want a randomized quicksort, you want to choose a random index between `left` and `right` inclusive, so the formula needs to be changed as follows:

```
  pivotIndex := left + (random number between 0 and right-left inclusive)
```

So, for example, if `left = 5` and `right = 7`, then you want `pivotIndex` to be `5 + x` where `x` is a random number between `0` and `7-5=2` inclusive.

Since `Random.nextInt(n)` has an *exclusive* upper bound, translating this to Java would be something like:

```
int pivotIndex = lo + rand.nextInt(hi - lo + 1);
```

---

#### Final correction

You've made a common mistake for beginners here:

```
    // HORRIBLE FORMATTING! Don't do this!
    if (arr[i]<=pivotValue)
    swap(arr, storeIndex, i);
    storeIndex = storeIndex ++;
```

If you noticed the pseudocode above, both statements are supposed to be part of the `if` body, but the above code, when properly indented and with braces added, is really this:

```
    // PROPER FORMATTING! Reveals bug instantly!
    if (arr[i]<=pivotValue) {
        swap(arr, storeIndex, i);
    }
    storeIndex = storeIndex ++;
```

The fix, therefore is to move the `storeIndex` increment to the `if` body like this:

```
    // Corrected according to pseudocode!
    if (arr[i]<=pivotValue) {
        swap(arr, storeIndex, i);
        storeIndex = storeIndex ++;
    }
```

Or you can also just do:

```
    // Nice and clear!
    if (arr[i]<=pivotValue) {
        swap(arr, storeIndex++, i);
    }
```

The lessons from this latest update is:

- Always indent your code properly

  - A good IDE can make this a breeze, you really have no excuse
- Make a habit of putting braces on `if` statements, even when they're not strictly necessary

  - Many subtle bugs are due to omission of braces
- Use post/pre-increments sensibly

  - Like many things, they can be abused beyond comprehension, but used appropriately and idiomatically they lead to concise and readable code

---

#### One last thing

When I mentioned `.length` of arrays, I meant that instead of this:

```
int[] A = {2, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1, 6, 8};
QuickSort(A, 0, 8); // BAD! Don't hardcode array length!
```

You should do this:

```
int[] arr = {2, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1, 6, 8};
QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1); // GOOD!
```

Comment: I have a question the nextInt() is not a static method!!! how can I call it like what you have written above??

Comment: @matin1234: I'm sorry that it was a bit confusing. By `Random.nextInt(int n)`, I mean `nextInt(int n)` on a `Random` instance, so it's similar to what you're doing with `nextInt()`, but just give it the extra parameter instead of doing `%` afterward.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: It’s (supposed to be) randomized quicksort. The only difference is that it uses a random element as the pivot. This shifts the frequency of encountering a worst case *significantly* and is one of the best strategies to improve quicksort (in particular when working on unsafe input that may have been fabricated by a malicious source to provoke a worst-case – used e.g. in DDOS attacks).

Comment: thanks a lot for your helping and I have done like what you have written(I have edited my post) but it does not sort my array!!!

Comment: +1 for a very good job being instructive rather than just giving the solution, polygenelubricants

Comment: thanks a lot ,yes you are right I will pey attention more to not do these mistakes again!! thanks a lot for your attention to my problem!!
really thanks

Answer (score 0):

The random generator produces positive and negative values. That's why eventually you call swap with a negative `q` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
swap(A, p, rand.nextInt() % (q+1));
```

The random integer generated may be below p, clearly you would want it to be something between p and q.

Answer (score 0):

As this is ***not*** homework, and I'd take the *homework* category to encompass self-learning, you should just use the standard [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29).